# Changing the body background dynamically with vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, vue.js

I am working on a form creation where I would like the user to choose a background color for their form. **This color choice changes the background color of the body tag.** I give them the options of colors and whichever color they choose should automatically change the background color.

I am doing this project with laravel and Vue. I am wondering what is the best way of dynamically doing this as right now I am not having much luck.

I have discovered a few ways of doing this. The first way is by creating a beforeCreate hook that changes the background color of the body, like so:

```
beforeCreate() {
        this.color = 'bc-header-red';
        document.body.className = this.color;
    },
```

However this does not let me update the background color like I want it to, not even with an update() hook.

The second option is to do a similar implementation as this one that I found, [link to jsfiddle](https://codepen.io/ahmedtarek2134/pen/VpLeEw). Basically, I can v-bind the style of the body tag to some value. However the problem with this is that by body tag is in my laravel blade file, not in the vue js file. Could I move it?

What are some other possible implementations or things that I could do instead? Thanks!

Comment: Specific reason for using vue?

Comment: familiarity and going to need it for other requirements in the project

Comment: Are you working on a component?

Comment: Yes I am working on a 'CreateGame' component. However, I want to be able to change the body tag of the entire page, not just the background of the component.

Comment: Put an immediate watcher on `this.color`.  Set the body class in the watcher.  Change `this.color` freely.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the vue `$emit`:

Inside your Vue component, you should have a method that handles the color choice, like this one:

```js
handleColorChoice() {
    this.color = this.colorChosen;
    document.body.className = this.color;
}
```

Just change it to emit the chosen color:

```js
handleColorChoice() {
    this.color = this.colorChosen;
    document.body.className = this.color;
    this.$root.$emit('body-background-color', this.colorChosen);
}
```

Now, you have an [event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#ad), and can [listen to it](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Listening-to-Events) on your main component:

Within your main component, inside the `mounted` method:

```
mounted() {
    this.$root.$on('body-background-color', function(color) {
        //handle the background color change here  
    });
}
```

Hope it helps.